# Manually commiting in Rebus with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, rebus

Using Kafka as the transport by way of [this lib](https://github.com/glazkovalex/Rebus.Kafka), is there a way with Rebus to give control on when a consumer will commit a message? I want to consume an event from Kafka, do some work which could possibly except/fail, and only if it succeeded tell Kafka to move the offset forward.

Comment: I am the author of the library you use "Rebus.Kafka". 
You write: "only if it succeeded tell Kafka to move the offset forward". Please tell us what it means to refuse to receive a message that your client code could not process without errors. Do you want to stop receiving any new messages if an exception occurred in your code while processing a message? Please provide a more detailed case that you want to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of the library you use ["Rebus.Kafka"](https://github.com/glazkovalex/Rebus.Kafka). You can only stop accepting publications completely by unsubscribing from your subscription. Then roll back the offset and re-process the queue.  To want to stop processing messages is an unnatural desire for bus users.
As an alternative to stopping the bus, you can consider the following options:

1. [Handler pipeline](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Handler-pipeline)
2. [Automatic retries and error handling](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling)
3. [Workers and parallelism](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Workers-and-parallelism)

Please provide a more detailed case that you want to implement.

**Addition:**

If you are not satisfied with the default option EnableAutoCommit = true, you can set its value, as well as all other parameters for the producer and consumer in the configuration parameters.

```
EnableAutoCommit = false,
```

How this is done is shown in this example of using transport ["Rebus.Kafka"](https://github.com/glazkovalex/Rebus.Kafka): https://github.com/glazkovalex/Rebus.Kafka/blob/master/Examples/Scaleout.Producer/Program.cs

Notice that the current version of the transport with disabled autoCommit, receives five messages and after processing moves the pointer. In other words, if the service is interrupted with autoCommit disabled, the service can re-process up to five messages when restarting. The number of these re-processed messages can be changed in future versions of the transport ["Rebus.Kafka"](https://github.com/glazkovalex/Rebus.Kafka).

Comment: Thanks for responding @Mentor. Basically, I'm looking for a solution for the data loss problem as described [here](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/kafka-consumer-config-auto-commit-data-loss/). As I understand it, one way to implement with Kafka (ie, without an abstraction library like Rebus) would be to turn off auto commit, and only commit when you've completed processing a message. That way, if something goes wrong, the message will eventually be re-delivered. I believe this is a prescribed flow from Kafka, for their version of 'Exactly Once' delivery, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is how you should use Apache Kafka. Set the consumer parater EnableAutoCommit = false in the transport configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[Rebus.Kafka version 3.0.0](https://github.com/glazkovalex/Rebus.Kafka) now supports RetryStrategy - [automatic retries and error handling](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling). Confirmations of receipt of messages are now sent not after they are received, but only after successful processing of messages or sending them to the error topic. That is, now the handler does not need to ensure successful processing or redirection of unsuccessful messages and you can rely on the Rebus bus [automatic retrieves and error handling](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling).

That is, now, as you wanted, the committing does not occur after the message is delivered, but only after its successful processing or resending to the error queue.